# Easy to learn jazz songs

Tags: jazz, piano

I'm learning to play jazz on the piano. Can you suggest popular jazz songs that's not overly complex to learn? For example, I enjoy playing "Autumn Leaves" and would like to broaden my repertoire.

Comment: Questions asking for lists are generally out of scope for this forum.  I would look for "easy jazz standards" on or "songs like Autumn Leaves" or "All of Me" on Google.

Comment: Will do. Thank you, Duston.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Misty or Blue In Green by Bill Evans, songs from Nat King Cole and Dave Brubeck.
You can also check this [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@TonyWinston/videos)(some are transcripts) for sheet music.

Comment: Thank you very much, Howard. I love the songs in the videos, great explanations and beautiful sounds. Thank you!